# Найти максимально возможное произведение элементов массива в заданном промежутке

Tags: c#

Имеется число, которое мы раскладываем на простые множители. Нужно найти такое произведение его элементов, чтобы оно было максимально возможным для заданного промежутка, если для заданного промежутка невозможно найти такое произведение, то следует вывести -1.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace probka
{
 class Program
 {
     static List<int> Delitely(int k)//Нахождение всех делителей
     {
         var Delitely = new List<int>();
         var Del = 2;
         while (k % Del == 0)
         {
             Delitely.Add(Del);
             k /= Del;
         }
         Del = 3;
         while (Math.Pow(Del, 2) <= k)
         {
             if (k % Del == 0)
             {
                 Delitely.Add(Del);
                 k /= Del;
             }
             else
             {
                 Del += 2;
             }
         }
         if (k > 1)
         {
             Delitely.Add(k);
         }
         return Delitely;
     }
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         int[] mass = Delitely(a).ToArray();//массив простых множителей числа а
         int max = a;
         Console.WriteLine("Все делители: " + string.Join(" ", mass));
         int start = 1000;
         int end = 10000;
         int i = 0;
         if ((max >= start) && (max <= end))//если число уже входит в нужный промежуток
             max = max;
         else if (max < start)//если число меньше минимальной границы
             max = -1;
         else
             while (max > end)
             {
                 max /= mass[i];
                 i++;
                 if (i>=mass.Length)
                 {
                     max = -1;
                     break;
                 }
             }
         Console.WriteLine(max);
     }
 }
}
```

Если просто находить всевозможные произведения чисел, то программа получается неэффективная(при больших числах количество множителей много), поэтому я шел от самого числа и делил его на множители начиная сначала, но это идея провалилась, так как при введение числа а=1000000 программа выводит 3125, в то время , как 5×5×5×5×5×2=6250.

Comment: *Нужно найти такое произведение его элементов, чтобы оно было максимально возможным для заданного промежутка* Это просто поиск наибольшего делителя числа в заданном промежутке.

Comment: *при введение числа а=1000000 программа выводит 3125, в то время , как 5×5×5×5×5×2=6250* Ну вообще-то диапазон задан от 1000 до 10000, так что ответ должен быть 10000.

Comment: 6250 - я привел для возможного примера, какие значения нужно ожидать

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Comment: @aepot При параметрах а=`1000000`, min=`1000`, max=`10000` по условиям задачи программа должна выдать `10000`, при этом автор ожидает `6250`, а программа выдает `3125`

Comment: Нужно найти максимально возможное произведение из простых множителей и чтобы это произведение попадало в заданный диапазон. Программа при  а=1000000 выводит 3125, в то время как существует минимум число 6250, которое можно получить и которое больше того, что выводит программа. Если существует произведение из элементов массива, которое больше(максимально возможное), нужно получить его.

Answer (score 0):

Используя [решето эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) находите все простые числа в диапазоне от 2 до √(a).

Дальше путем деления на каждое простое число без остатка находите простые множители самого числа `a` и максимального числа диапазона.

Потом ищете общие множители в обоих массивах, полученных ранее.

По окончанию необходимо найти произведение общих множителей и не забыть сравнить с минимальной границей диапазона.

Comment: Вы что-то не то придумали.

Comment: @MBo  Почему? Нужно найти максимальное произведение простых множителей?

Comment: Множители максимального числа диапазона тут не помогут